# Only whole node in preview

Tags: drupal, preview, teaser

Is it possible to show only the whole node when clicking on "Preview", not also the teaser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [theme_node_preview](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/theme_node_preview/6) in your theme, to remove the code related to $preview_trimmed_version. More specifically, add the following code to the template.php file in your theme.

```
function phptemplate_node_preview($node) {
  $output = '<div class="preview">';
  $output .= node_view($node, 0, FALSE, 0);
  $output .= "</div>\n";
  return $output;
}
```